# How to prevent Xpath recursion

Tags: xpath

Given I have this (unknown) document structure, how do I write xpath to select div1 and div2, i.e. all divs, but not recursivelly (no divs, contained anywhere within another divs)?

I couldn't find any documentation that would point me in this direction, all I could manage is to select ALL divs, i.e. div1, div2 and div3 (with `//div` expression), but I want to exclude div2 here as it is the descendant div of another one.

(I need a generic solution to select tags not recursivelly, the ids here are for explanatory purposes only.)

```
  ...some unknown structure with no divs...
  <div id="1">
    ...some unknown structure with no divs...
    <div id="2"></div>
    ...some unknown structure with no divs...
  </div>
  ...some unknown structure with no divs...
  <div id="3"></div>
  ...some unknown structure with no divs...
```

Comment: "I couldn't find any documentation" - perhaps you made the mistake of searching for a specific solution to this specific problem, rather than reading about the general rules for axes and predicates so that you could construct your own solution.

Comment: @MichaelKay I did, but Xpath docs I managed to find are pretty dry, Martin's answer made it all click for me. Some people learn much faster with tutorials and examples... at least I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select `//div[not(ancestor::div)]` you select all `div` elements that don't have any ancestor also being a `div`.

If you have access to XPath 3.1 or 3.0 you can also use the `outermost` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-outermost as it "returns every node within the sequence that does not have another node within the sequence as an ancestor" so "the expression `outermost(//div)` returns those div elements that are not contained within further div elements".